# How to use Mono.dematerialize()?

Tags: java, project-reactor

As subject, I don't understand what is the use-case and how to use it.

Digging into the source code seems to be casting the mono itself from `Mono<T>` into `Mono<Signal<X>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in the javadoc, `dematerialize` only makes sense if the `Flux` on which it is called is a `Flux<Signal<T>>`

It is the inverse of `materialize`, which aims at converting every signal in the source to `onNext` notifications.

Typical use would be to monitor all that happens in a `Flux`, not just value signals, then revert back to the original flux: to emulate the `log()` operator, you could use a `materialize().doOnNext(System.out::println).dematerialize()` for instance...

Comment: Thanks @simon-baslé, my second question is what would be the use-case in real world application?

Comment: And what are the pros and cons if we compare it with log()?